# Laravel: Confirmation deletion does not work

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm having a problem with deleting confirmation; specifically, when I click on the delete button, the item is deleted directly without the window for confirming the deletion appearing first.

Can someone help me?

```js
function confirmDelete(){
    let deleteLink = document.querySelector('.delete');

    deleteLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

        if (choice) {
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('action');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<form action="{{ route('client.destroy',compact('client'))}}" method="POST">

    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('client.edit', compact('client'))}}">Edit</a>

    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="confirmDelete()" data-confirm="Sure?">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No need for `onclick` when you have an eventlistener. Remove the `onclick` part and move the code outside of your function

Comment: @brombeer Can you show me with an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should prevent default behaviour(which is submitting form onclick) of input:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault();confirmDelete()"
```

Comment: It does not work. I get ```confirmDelete is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick```

Comment: It means it is working). You already prevented deleting your record. That was not even calling your function but now it calls. Make sure you have connected your js to html

Comment: I missed calling the function. However, it is not deleted from the database

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Set button type button and set id to form.

```
<form action="{{ route('client.destroy',compact('client'))}}" method="POST" id="form_id">

  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('client.edit',compact('client'))}}">Edit</a>

@csrf
@method('DELETE')

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="confirmDelete()" data-confirm="Sure?">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Some change in your function.

```
function confirmDelete() {
  let deleteLink = document.querySelector('.delete');

  deleteLink.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let choice = confirm($(this).data('confirm'));

    if (choice) {
      $('#form_id').submit();
      // window.location.href = this.getAttribute('action');
    }
  });
}
```

If you do this for multiple client make sure FORM ID is unique.

Comment: That's really help me today